# TestRail connection timing out due to a server issue [Status Code 500]

Tags: python, http, testrail

I have a `script` that tries to connect to `TestRail` and it had been working for a while. Recently, the script has been timing out while trying to perform a `GET` request:

```
INFO:root: 
{"message":"HTTPSConnectionPool(host='testrail.zooxlabs.com', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: 
/index.php?/api/v2/get_case_fields (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x7f41590e05f8>: Failed to establish a new connection: 
[Errno 110] Connection timed out',))","statusCode":500}
```

The question I have is if this is a `server error` because normally, a request time out is a `Status Code 408` rather than a `500` error.

Comment: Can you confirm that issue is still there or not? If not, what was the solution for that, will help community.